# Why does my .NET Standard 2.0 (multi-targetting) project has a warning on one of the dependent assemblies?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I have a project that is currently targetting `NetStandard1.4`.

I'm trying to make it multi-target-frameworks for:

- `net461`
- `netstandard14`
- `netstandard20`

the rational is for a particular framework (an app targets), only pull down the minimum number of assemblies. So in the example above, `ns14` has a min framework of `461`, but an app that is targeting `net461` pulls down some core stuff which people are saying adds extra noise, when those assemblies are not getting used.

When I try and target those 3 frameworks, I get some warning in the `NetStandard2.0` version.

[image]

I try hovering the mouse over that assembly in Visual Studio but no tool-tip displays. Also, the errorlist or output (build) window has no explanation there.

Is there a way I can see what the warning is? Maybe even via CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are referencing `System.Net.Http` in .netStandard projects. This reference is already present in `NetStandard.Library`, so you don't need to add it. Most of the time, you should only reference projects or NuGet package.

On my computer, `dotnet build` does fail with the following warning:

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.100-preview-007326\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2051,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "System.Net.Http". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

If you don't want to add a reference to NetStandard.Library, the solution is to add reference only to the net461 version using the `Condition` attribute:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net461;netstandard1.4;netstandard2.0</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net461'">
  <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
</ItemGroup>
```